# Disable Window Menu

Tags: c, windows, opengl, menu

In my C OpenGL app the window style requires WS_SYSMENU to show the close and minimize buttons, but it also brings up a stupid menu everytime I press alt.

How can I disable this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to handle WM_DEADCHAR and WM_SYSCHAR and discard the press of the ALT key (or do your own processing).  This will still allow the user to activate the menu with the mouse and from the taskbar... which is why you really shouldn't disable it completely, users like to be able to manipulate windows from the taskbar.